# how to get parent repeater item from child repeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have two repeater which are nested..Means there is one repeater and inside that i have another repeater.

I want data in following format:

```
*Transaction Id:1xasd2*
Product1  2  500
*Transaction Id:2asd21*
Product2  1  100
Product3  2  200
```

So how can i achieve this?

Comment: What is the problem with your current design of nested repeaters?

Comment: i want that when i bind child repeater i want transaction id of the parent.so how can i get it???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think yr looking for:

```
Protected Sub rptMaster_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles rptMaster.ItemDataBound
    Dim drv As DataRowView = e.Item.DataItem
    Dim rptChild As Repeater = CType(e.Item.FindControl("rptChild"), Repeater)
    If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Or e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
            'Get TransactionID here from master repeater
            Dim lblTransactionID  As Label = drv("TransactionID")
            'bind child repeater here
            rptChild.DataSource = GetData()
            rptChild.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

can use:

```
var repeater = (Repeater)sender;
var parentItem = (RepeaterItem)repeater.NamingContainer;
<Object> parentDataItem = parentItem.DataItem as <Object>;
(parentDataItem.property)
```

Worked!